# Android WebView Download Listener

Tags: android, android-webview

Did anyone know how to get the full url to the content that should be downloaded in webview.
I notice there is  setDownloadListener (DownloadListener listener) method where we can get the url onDownloadStart method.

But i have problem when i open page A, i click hyperlink in page A and directly open a new page B. In page B i download some files so i want to know the full url of the file i just download, but i can't use the method above. Any solution??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved same problem in android eclipse, first i have created a `webview` then added `downloadListner`, after that i am checking either machine is connected to the internet or not, if so, the URL is loaded into `webview`, else an error message appears "No Network", That's it. You can check the code below which i am using in my app.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
        {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,StringcontentDisposition, String mimetype,long contentLength) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);   
            }
        });
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
        connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
        connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if( wifi.isAvailable() )
        {
            wv.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
        }
        else if( mobile.isAvailable() )
        {
            wv.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Network " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }        
    }
}
```